# Javascript Textarea Issue

Tags: html

I'm importing data from youtube into a textarea using Javascript.

If you I simply place my Javascript code onto a blank area it displays the information fine, but for some reason it doesn't allow me to paste a same code into a **textarea**.

Here is my code:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="bandsvideodescription" name="bandsvideodescription">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function youtubeFeedCallback( data )
  {
    document.writeln( '' + data.entry[ "media$group" ][ "media$description" ].$t.replace( /\n/g, '' ) + '' );
  }
</script>
</textarea>
```

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textareas are defined as:

```
<!ELEMENT TEXTAREA - - (#PCDATA)       -- multi-line text field -->
```

They can only contain PCDATA, which means *no elements* (including `<script>` elements).

Move the script to after the control, then get a reference to it (e.g. with `document.getElementById`) and set its `value` property instead of trying to write it out as the document loads.

Comment: `document.getElementById('id-of-element').value = something;`

Answer (score 0):

Your script is interpreted as HTML code. You should escape angle brackets, like this:

```
<textarea rows="10" id="bandsvideodescription" name="bandsvideodescription">
&lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt;
  function youtubeFeedCallback( data )
  {
    document.writeln( '' + data.entry[ "media$group" ][ "media$description" ].$t.replace( /\n/g, '' ) + '' );
  }
&lt;/script&gt;
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't put script tags `<script>` in a textarea you can't even put any html tag in a textarea.

It will consider it as the default value ;)

And escaping it with `&gt;` our `&lt;` will nt change anything because it's already escaped in the textarea to show it as simple  text